# Loop 2d array in same html tag on thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have this html to render in thymleaf:

```html
 <div id="puzzle">
     <div number="1" class="cell-puzzle row-1 col-1">1</div>
     <div number="2" class="cell-puzzle row-1 col-2">2</div>
     <div number="3" class="cell-puzzle row-1 col-3">3</div>
     <div number="4" class="cell-puzzle row-1 col-4">4</div>
     <div number="5" class="cell-puzzle row-2 col-1">5</div>
     <div number="6" class="cell-puzzle row-2 col-2">6</div>
     <div number="7" class="cell-puzzle row-2 col-3">7</div>
     <div number="8" class="cell-puzzle row-2 col-4">8</div>
     <div number="9" class="cell-puzzle row-3 col-1">9</div>
     <div number="10" class="cell-puzzle row-3 col-2">10</div>
     <div number="11" class="cell-puzzle row-3 col-3">11</div>
     <div number="12" class="cell-puzzle row-3 col-4">12</div>
     <div number="13" class="cell-puzzle row-4 col-1">13</div>
     <div number="14" class="cell-puzzle row-4 col-2">14</div>
     <div number="15" class="cell-puzzle row-4 col-3">15</div>
     <div number="0" class="cell-puzzle row-4 col-4 cell-puzzle-zero"></div>
</div>
```

here is implementation on thymleaf:

```html
<div id="puzzle">
   <span th:each="row,iter  : *{matrix}" >
     <div th:each="col, iter2: ${row}" th:attr="number=${iter.index + 1}" th:class="'cell-puzzle row-' + ${iter.index + 1} + ' col-' + ${iter2.index + 1}" th:text="${col}"></div>
   </span>
<div number="0" class="cell-puzzle row-4 col-4 cell-puzzle-zero"></div>
</div>
```

i need to wrap `div` inside `span` to have two `th:each` 
output html will be different with original. 
When i try to merge two `th:each` into same `div` then it throw
error:

```html
<div id="puzzle">
     <div th:each="row,iter  : *{matrix}" th:each="col, iter2: ${row}" th:attr="number=${iter.index + 1}" th:class="'cell-puzzle row-' + ${iter.index + 1} + ' col-' + ${iter2.index + 1}" th:text="${col}"></div>
<div number="0" class="cell-puzzle row-4 col-4 cell-puzzle-zero"></div>
</div>
```

error:

```
org.attoparser.ParseException: (Line = 31, Column = 74) Malformed markup: Attribute "th:each" appears more than once in element
```

I know the alternative way of this one is translate 2d array into 1d array, but then we need to calculate index manually. so please skip this way \

Does anyone know how to use only thymleaf on this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<th:block />` instead of the `<span />`.  You can put a `th:each` in it, and it won't output anything.

```
<div id="puzzle">
    <th:block th:each="row,iter  : *{matrix}">
      <div th:each="col, iter2: ${row}" th:attr="number=${iter.index + 1}" th:class="'cell-puzzle row-' + ${iter.index + 1} + ' col-' + ${iter2.index + 1}" th:text="${col}"></div>
    </th:block>
    <div number="0" class="cell-puzzle row-4 col-4 cell-puzzle-zero"></div>
</div>
```